# DLNA Server in python in home network

Tags: python, webos, lg, smart-tv, dlna

In my pc, how can i listen incoming connection as a DLNA server?

On my TV there is the possibility for get media from a DLNA server, i would write a simple python script that grant access at TV to my files.

The ends are:

- LG webOS smartTV
- macOS

Answer (score 1):

One project I've found is Cohen3. Does not look as too much alive, but at least supports Python version 3: https://github.com/opacam/Cohen3

There's also a Coherence project (it seems Cohen3 is somehow derived from it, not sure): https://gitlab.digitalcourage.de/coherence

Answer (score -3):

There is already server app doing it [Serviio](http://serviio.org/) I already using this on windows 10 and raspberry pi 2 and 3 and it works well, easy to setup by web app and you'll save a time with making your own solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21145250)

Comment: this is not link for answer but for recommended software to use